Game with objects, 4 objects in 4 slots, but each guess is remembered
Let's say that there is a game that requires you to put letters A,B,C,D in some order.
If you placed A on 1st position and it was wrong, you remove it and remember that it was wrong on 1st position. For example:
guess1: A, B, C, D -> turns out B was on correct position
After that guess you know that:

B is on 2nd position
A can't be on 1st position
C can't be on 3rd position
D can't be on 4th position.

After it you take another guess, and so on.
I know there is 4 maximum guesses and 9 combinations like this
[4,0,0,0]   [2,2,0,0]   [1,3,0,0]   [1,0,3,0]   [0,4,0,0]   [0,2,2,0]   [0,1,3,0]   [0,0,4,0]   [0,0,0,4], where numbers are "right guess amount", and from left to right it is [1st guess, 2nd guess, 3rd guess, 4th guess].
So for example in [2,2,0,0] it is 2 guessed right in 1st and 2nd guess and 0 in 3rd and 4th guess.
My question is how do I calculate number of possible outcomes?
Or a combination of guess_number and correct_guess that would lead me to calculating for example that when 1st guess was 0 correct_guesses and 2nd guess was 2 correct_guesses I'm left with only a possibility for a 2 correct_guesses in 3rd guess.

"number of possible outcomes" is the 9 sequences of correct per guess, or something else?

It's set of correct rows of guesses,
for example if 1st guess has 4 correct letters, it is one possible outcome
on the other hand possible outcome is 2 correct letters in 1st guess and 2 correct letters in 2nd guess.
It is worth noting that it is impossible to have more guesses in that second scenario, because of "remembering" previously placed letters.
